# how to read local json file in flutter

Tags: json, flutter

I am trying to read a local json file named "catalog.json" I wrote all the nessessary codes but it's showing this error "lateinitializationError: Field 'catalogdata' has not been initialized."
then i tried by initializing the 'catalogdata' variable but then it shows that 'catalogdata' variable is empty . I dont know how to solve it . Please help me.
my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homepage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  late List catalogdata;
  Future<String> loadData() async {
    var data = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/images/files/catalog.json");
    setState(() {
      catalogdata = json.decode(data);
    });
    return "success";
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    this.loadData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Homepage"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          catalogdata[0],
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried add `await` before `this.loadData();`

Comment: Do you have idea about reading it from app storage path.. ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Here’s sample.json:**

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "p1",
      "name": "Item 1",
      "description": "Description 1"
    },
    {
      "id": "p2",
      "name": "Item 2",
      "description": "Description 2"
    },
    {
      "id": "p3",
      "name": "Item 3",
      "description": "Description 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

The code which is used to fetch data from the JSON file (see the full code below):

```
Future<void> readJson() async {
  final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/sample.json');
  final data = await json.decode(response);
// ... 
}
```

Declare the json file in the assets section in your pubspec.yaml file:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/sample.json
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

 void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
 }

 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return const MaterialApp(
  // Hide the debug banner
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  title: 'Kindacode.com',
  home: HomePage(),
);
}
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
_HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List _items = [];

// Fetch content from the json file
Future<void> readJson() async {
final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/sample.json');
final data = await json.decode(response);
setState(() {
  _items = data["items"];
});
}

  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
    centerTitle: true,
    title: const Text(
      'Kindacode.com',
    ),
  ),
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Load Data'),
          onPressed: readJson,
        ),

        // Display the data loaded from sample.json
        _items.isNotEmpty
            ? Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: _items.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Card(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: ListTile(
                        leading: Text(_items[index]["id"]),
                        title: Text(_items[index]["name"]),
                        subtitle: Text(_items[index]["description"]),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              )
            : Container()
      ],
    ),
  ),
 );
 }
 }
```

Comment: thanks bro you saved me. I am new to flutter . I am trying to learn it . thanks for your help

Comment: It's relly working advice! Biggest thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> it's showing this error "lateinitializationError: Field 'catalogdata'
> has not been initialized." then I tried by initializing the
> 'catalogdata'

**While using      ***late***       before variables make sure that, the variable must be initialized later. Otherwise, you can encounter a runtime error when the variable is used.**

If you didn't **add the correct location catalog.json  in pubsec.yaml your variable catalog didn't gets the correct value so the late variable is not** initialized.

[image]

So you must add asset path in pubsec.yaml

```
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/images/files/catalog.json
```

Another case here is **JSON.decode() return map<string,dynamic> value here you set list.maybe that also cause the problem** and not initialised.

[image]

instead of this `late List catalogdata;`  use this  `late var catalogdata;` or  late Map<string,dynamic> catalogdata;

**Sample Code**

***Catalog.json***

```
{
  "name": "lava",
  "Catagory": "man"
}
```

**Main.dart**

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class AppRoutes {
  static String detail = "/Detail";
  static String Page2 = "/FilterBeacon";
  static String Page1 = "/FilterPoint";
  static String home = "/";
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      // key: constItem.navigatorKey,

      initialRoute: "/",
      routes: {
        AppRoutes.home: (context) => Home(),
      },
      title: _title,
      // home: ,
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

var _index = 0;

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Homepage(),
    );
  }
}

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homepage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  late var catalogdata;

  Future<String> loadDatas() async {
    var data = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/images/files/catalog.json");
    // setState(() {
      catalogdata = json.decode(data);
    // });
    return "success";
  }

  Future<String> loadData() async {
    var data = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/images/files/catalog.json");
    setState(() {
    catalogdata = json.decode(data);
    });
    return "success";
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    loadData();
    // loadData().then((value) => catalogdata=value);
  } // String jsons = "";

  // @override
  // Future<void> initState() async {
  //   super.initState();
  //   await loadData();
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var futureBuilder = FutureBuilder(
          future:  loadData(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)
              return Center(
                child: Text(
                  catalogdata.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(),
                ),
              );
            else
              return Container();
          });
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Homepage"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          catalogdata.toString(),
          style: TextStyle(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```